# Is There a Basis Free Definition of the Pfaffian

Tags: linear-algebra, multilinear-algebra, bilinear-form, exterior-algebra, pfaffian

$\DeclareMathOperator{\pf}{pf}$
I recently came across a delightful fact that:

*The determinant of a $2n\times 2n$ skew-symmetric matrix is a the square of a certain polynomial called the pfaffian.*

I was looking for a "conceptual proof" of the above. So naturally I first wanted to understand pfaffians.
The description of pfaffian I have seen ([here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pfaffian)) is not very satisfactory to me.

> **Question.** Is there a notion of the pfaffian of a linear operator?

A promising description of the Pfaffian is available on the [above mentioned](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pfaffian) article: Assume for simplicity that the entries of $M$ are complex numbers, and the $ij$-th entry be written as $a_{ij}$.
Let $e_1, \ldots, e_{2n}$ be the standard basis of $\mathbf C^{2n}$.
To $M$ we associate a bivector $\omega=\sum_{i<j}a_{ij}\ e_i\wedge e_j$ and let $\omega^n$ denote the wedging of $\omega$ with itself $n$ times.
Then
$$\frac{1}{n!}\omega^n= \pf(M)e_1\wedge \cdots \wedge e_{2n}$$

> If you know a nice proof of the fact mentioned above then please share it.

Comment: Is there a basis free definition of the determinant? I don't think so...

Comment: @darijgrinberg If $T:V\to V$ is a linear operator on an $n$-dimensional vector space $V$, then we know that $\bigwedge^n T:\bigwedge^n V\to \bigwedge^n V$ satisfies $\bigwedge^n T= cI$ for some constant $c$. This constant is defined to be the determinant of the operator $T$.

Comment: Ah! I thought the proof of welldefinedness should also be basis-free.

Comment: @darijgrinberg Proof of well-definedness of the determinant? If one goes by defining the determinant of $T$ by first forming the matrix representation $M$ of $T$ and then writing $\det T=\det M$, then yes, there is a well-definedness issue. Of course, in the exterior power approach there is no such problem.

Comment: In the exterior power approach the problem is to verify that $\wedge^n V$ is nonzero.

Comment: core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82800447.pdf

Answer (score 5):

The Pfaffian only makes sense for skew-symmetric matrices in even dimensions, so there's no hope of generalizing it as far as an arbitrary linear operator.

One coordinate-free description of the input to the Pfaffian is that it is an element of the orthogonal Lie algebra $\mathfrak{so}(2n)$; in this incarnation the Pfaffian appears as an invariant polynomial on $\mathfrak{so}(2n)$ (so it is invariant under *orthogonal*, rather than arbitrary, changes of coordinates). It is in fact the polynomial which corresponds via [Chern-Weil theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chern%E2%80%93Weil_homomorphism) to the [Euler class](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_class); this is more or less the content of the [Chern-Gauss-Bonnet theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_Gauss%E2%80%93Bonnet_theorem). The Pfaffian squaring to the determinant corresponds via Chern-Weil theory to the Euler class squaring to the top [Pontryagin class](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pontryagin_class).

It should be possible to give a conceptual proof that the Pfaffian squares to the determinant using the wedge product definition. As in user357105's comment to his answer, the setting to work in is a finite-dimensional real (for simplicity) inner product space $V$; here you can identify skew-symmetric linear operators $T : V \to V$ with elements of $\wedge^2 V$ (both of which can in turn be identified with the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{so}(V)$), and you use this identification to relate the determinant and the Pfaffian. I haven't worked through the details, though.

Answer (score 4):

The Pfaffian is an invariant of matrices, but not of underlying linear operators. Two skew-symmetric matrices that are similar can have different Pfaffians: for example, $$\mathrm{Pf}\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ -1 & 0 \end{pmatrix} = 1, \; \; \mathrm{Pf} \begin{pmatrix} 0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix} = -1.$$ In other words, the Pfaffian depends not only on the linear operator, but also on a choice of basis - so there can be no basis-free definition.

Comment: However, it is well-defined up to a choice of basis of $\Omega^{2n}(V)$ (the space of alternating forms on $V$) - essentially an "orientation" on $V$: you can identify skew-symmetric or skew-adjoint maps $T$ with alternating $2$-forms via $\omega(v,w) := \langle v, Tw \rangle$, where $\langle -,- \rangle$ is a fixed bilinear form. Then the Pfaffian becomes the map $\Omega^2(V) \rightarrow \Omega^{2n}(V)$, $\omega \mapsto \frac{1}{n!} \omega^n$; essentially as you mentioned in the question.

Comment: What does it mean by it is well-defined up to a choice of basis of $\Omega^{2n}(V)$? In Qiaochu's answer, it is invariant to an _orthogonal_ change of basis. I can't seem to equate these two. Any reference on what you mentioned here?

Answer (score 2):

Let $(V,\Omega)$ be a vector space of dimension $2n$ with a nonzero $\Omega\in \bigwedge^{2n} V^*$.

Let $A$ be an alternating bilinear form on $V$. Then $A\in \bigwedge^2 V^*$ and $\Omega$ spans $\bigwedge^{2n} V^*$.

Define the Pfaffian $Pf(A)$ of $A$ w.r.t. $\Omega$ by
$$Pf(A)\Omega:=\frac{A^{\wedge n}}{n!}\in  \bigwedge { }^{2n} V^*$$

If a basis is chosen and $A$ is represented by a matrix, then clearly $Pf(A)$ is a homogeneous polynomial of degree $n$ in the coefficients of $A$.

Let now $\omega$ be a symplectic form on $V$.
Then there exists $B\in \text{End}(V)$ such that $B^*\omega=A$. If $A$ is nondegenerate (thus also symplectic), this amounts to the fact that any two linear symplectic forms on $V$ are equivalent.

Since $A^{\wedge n}=(B^*\omega)^{\wedge n}=B^*\omega^{\wedge n}=\det(B)\omega^{\wedge n}$ we have $Pf(A)=\det(B)$, if $\omega$ is chosen such that $\omega^{\wedge n}/n!=\Omega$.

Fix an inner product on $V$. Then $\omega$ can be viewed as an endomorphism of $V$.
Since $B^T\omega B=A$, we have $\det(A)=\det(B)^2\det(\omega)$
and thus $$ \det(A)=Pf(A)^2\det(\omega).$$
If the inner product is such that $\det (\omega)=1$, this reduces to  $\det(A)=Pf(A)^2$.