# A non-zero quantity associated to an invertible skew-symmetric matrix of even order.

Tags: determinant, multilinear-algebra, pfaffian

**Once again, I failed to make a concise post so feel free to skip to the emphasized parts.**

In the context of symplectic and contact geometry, I would like to establish the following linear algebra fact:

> **Proposition.** Let $E$ be a real vector space of dimension $2n$ and let $\omega\in\Lambda^2 E^*$, then $\omega$ is non-degenerate if and only if $\omega^n$ is a volume form of $E$.

**Proof.** There exists $(\omega_{i,j})_{1\leqslant i,j\leqslant 2n}$ a skew-symmetric $2n\times 2n$ matrix with real entries such that, one has:
$$\omega=\sum_{i,j=1}^{2n}\omega_{i,j}\,\mathrm{d}x_i\wedge\mathrm{d}x_j.$$
A straightforward computation then leads to the following equality:
$$\omega^n=\left(\sum_{\sigma\in\mathfrak{S}_{2n}}\varepsilon(\sigma)\prod_{i=1}^n\omega_{\sigma(2i-1),\sigma(2i)}\right)\mathrm{d}x_1\wedge\cdots\wedge\mathrm{d}x_{2n},$$
where $\mathfrak{S}_{2n}$ stands for the permutation group on the set $\{1,\ldots,2n\}$ letters and $\varepsilon(\sigma)$ is the signature of $\sigma$.
Therefore, let us define the following quantity associated to $\omega$:

> $$\operatorname{vol}(\omega):=\sum_{\sigma\in\mathfrak{S}_{2n}}\varepsilon(\sigma)\prod_{i=1}^n\omega_{\sigma(2i-1),\sigma(2i)}.$$

The proof boils down to show that $(\omega_{i,j})_{1\leqslant i,j\leqslant 2n}$ is invertible if and only if $\operatorname{vol}(\omega)$ is non-zero. $\Box$

Hence, my question arises:

> **Question.** How can I show that $\operatorname{vol}(\omega)$ is non-zero if and only if  $(\omega_{i,j})_{1\leqslant i,j\leqslant 2n}$ is invertible?

I am aware that $\operatorname{vol}(\omega)=2^nn!\operatorname{pf}(\omega)$, where $\operatorname{pf}(\omega)$ is the Pfaffian of $\omega$ and that one has:
$$\det(\omega)=\operatorname{pf}(\omega)^2,\tag{1}$$
which immediately leads to the desired result, but $(1)$ is a pain to establish and I would like to avoid using it. If you are aware of a clever and rather elementary way to prove $(1)$, I will also be happy with it.

Any enlightenment will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: My guess is that one should see what happens to the Pfaffian (and the volume) when you change $\omega$ by an special orthogonal transformation $\omega \mapsto Q\,  \omega\,  Q^t$,  where  $Q \in \text{SO}(2n)$. Then use the spectral theory of skew symmetric matrices, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skew-symmetric_matrix#Spectral_theory).  See also Qiaochu Yuan's answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1376632/is-there-a-basis-free-definition-of-the-pfaffian?rq=1).

Comment: @fredgoodman Thank you for your hunch, it was a fruitful idea! I took the liberty to write a full answer below.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is based on [fredgoodman](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/124085/fredgoodman)'s suggestion in the comments.

In what follows, the key observation is that $\operatorname{vol}(\omega)$ is the unique scalar $\lambda$ such that $w^n=\lambda\,\mathrm{d}x_1\wedge\cdot\wedge dx_{2n}$.

> **Proposition.** Let $M$ be a $2n\times 2n$ matrix with real entries, then one has the following equality:
>   $$\textrm{vol}(M\omega{}^\intercal M)=\det(M)\operatorname{vol}(\omega).$$

**Proof.** Let us define $\omega':=M^*\omega$, then it is easily seen that on the level of matrices, one has:
$$\omega'=M\omega{}^\intercal M.$$
Besides, one has the following equality:
$${\omega'}^n=M^*\omega^n=M^*(\operatorname{vol}(\omega)\,\mathrm{d}x_1\wedge\ldots\wedge\mathrm{d}x_{2n})=\det(M)\operatorname{vol}(\omega)\,\mathrm{d}x_1\wedge\ldots\wedge\mathrm{d}x_{2n}.$$
Whence the result. $\Box$

> **Lemma.** Let $\omega:=\operatorname{diag}\left(\begin{bmatrix}0&\lambda_1\\-\lambda_1&0\end{bmatrix},\ldots,\begin{bmatrix}0&\lambda_n\\-\lambda_n&0\end{bmatrix},0,\ldots,0\right)$, then one has the following:
>   $$\operatorname{vol}(\omega)=2^nn!\lambda_1\ldots\lambda_n.$$
>   In particular, one has $\operatorname{vol}(\omega)^2=(2^nn!)^2\det(\omega)$.

**Proof.** By construction of the matrix, one has:
$$\omega=2\sum_{i=1}^n\lambda_i\,\mathrm{d}x_{2i-1}\wedge\mathrm{d}x_{2i}.$$
Therefore, by a straightforward computation, one has:
$$\begin{align}\omega^n&=2^n\sum_{i_1=1}^{n}\cdots\sum_{i_n=1}^{n}\lambda_{i_1}\ldots\lambda_{i_n}\,\mathrm{d}x_{2i_1-1}\wedge\mathrm{d}x_{2i_1}\wedge\ldots\wedge\mathrm{d}x_{2i_n-1}\wedge\mathrm{d}x_{2i_n},\\&=2^n\sum_{\sigma\in\mathfrak{S}_n}\lambda_{\sigma(1)}\ldots\lambda_{\sigma(n)}\,\mathrm{d}x_{2\sigma(1)-1}\wedge\mathrm{d}x_{2\sigma(1)}\wedge\cdots\wedge\mathrm{d}x_{2\sigma(n)-1}\wedge\mathrm{d}x_{2\sigma(n)},\notag\\&=2^n\sum_{\sigma\in\mathfrak{S}_n}(-1)^{2\varepsilon(\sigma)}\lambda_1\ldots\lambda_n\,\mathrm{d}x_1\wedge\cdots\wedge\mathrm{d}x_{2n},\\&=2^nn!\lambda_1\ldots\lambda_n\,\mathrm{d}x_1\wedge\ldots\wedge\mathrm{d}x_{2n}.\end{align}$$
Whence the result, since $\det(\omega)={\lambda_1}^2\ldots{\lambda_n}^2$. $\Box$

> **Theorem.** One has $\det(\omega)=\operatorname{pf}(\omega)^2$.

**Proof.** Using the spectral theorem for skew-symmetric along with the proposition and the lemma, one has:
$$\operatorname{vol}(\omega)^2=(2^nn!)^2\det(\omega).$$
Whence the result, since $\operatorname{vol}(\omega)=2^nn!\operatorname{pf}(\omega)$. $\Box$